# Pushing variable height child container to bottom of parent container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My parent div has a variable height depending on the size of the window.

I have an `#image-container` and a `#second-container` that I am trying to fit inside my parent div. My `#second-container` is also a variable height depending on the screen size and I am trying to get it to affix to the bottom of the parent container.

Right now I am accomplishing this via javascript but I was wondering if there was anyway to do this using pure css.

```js
    function resize() {
      var header_height = $("#header").height(),
          second_container = $("#second-container").height(),
          image_container = $("#image-container").height();

      document.getElementById('image-container').style.height = header_height - second_container +'px'; 
    }

    resize();
    $( window ).resize(function() { resize(); });
```

```css
*, *:before, *:after { -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; }

* { margin:0; padding:0 }

#header {
  background-color:#f0f0f0;
  height:100vh;
}

#image-container {
  background-image:url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1428509774491-cfac96e12253');
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center;
  height:50vh;
}



#second-container {
  font-size:0;
}

.grid { 
  vertical-align:top;
  display:inline-block;
  width:25%;
}

.box {
  padding-bottom:56.25%;
  border:1px solid #232323;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <div id="header">
    <div id="image-container"></div>
    
    <div id="second-container">
      <div class="grid">
        <div class="box"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid">
        <div class="box"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid">
        <div class="box"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid">
        <div class="box"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: `position: absolute; bottom: 0;` https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/nybhft18/

Comment: @ChrisG I don't want the `#second-container` to lay overtop of the image. That's the issue. The goal is to have the `#image-container` fill the remaining vertical space

Comment: In that case you can probably achieve this with the new flexbox CSS stuff.

Answer (score 0):

The solution would be to make the position of the header relative and the position of the container absolute and fixed to the bottom. This can be achieved by adding the following to your css:

CSS:

```
#header{
  position: absolute;
}

#second-container{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
}
```

Edit:

If you want to do this without absolute positioning the solution would be to make the image an object rather than a background. Here is a JSFiddle that shows this. You will have to modify the height/width some but this should solve your problem.

HTML:

```
<div id="header">
  <div id="second-container">
    <div class="image"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1428509774491-cfac96e12253"></div>
    <div class="grid">
      <div class="box"></div>
      </div>

    <div class="grid">
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid">
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid">
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

#header {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  height: 100vh;
  /* position: relative; */
  /* background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1428509774491-cfac96e12253'); */
  /* background-size: cover; */
  /* background-position: center; */
}

img{
  height:100vh;
  object-size:contain;
}

#second-container {
  font-size: 0;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100
}

.grid {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  background-color: #ddd;
  margin:0;
}

.box {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #232323 inset;
  height: 80px;
}
```

Comment: I don't want the `#second-container` to lay overtop of the image. The goal is to have the `#image-container` fill the remaining vertical space

Comment: @bryan See my updated solution. This will prevent overlapping.

Comment: What doesn't work about this? Based on the question this appeared to work on my screen. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/nybhft18/1/

Comment: The picture is fit for the height. I want it to fill the entire screen. Make your example full screen and you'll see

Comment: @bryan Then you just have to change the `object-size` property to `fill`. Try this (that is the only change made): https://jsfiddle.net/nybhft18/2/